# Alternatives to creating manifest.json in dynamics 365

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, dynamics-365

When trying to connect my Dynamics 365 with Google Firebase Cloud Messaging I came to this paragraph:

> You'll need to add a web app manifest that specifies the gcm_sender_id, a >hard-coded value indicating that FCM is authorized to send messages to this >app. If your app already has a manifest.json configuration file, make sure to >add the browser sender ID exactly as shown (do not change the value):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

But Dynamics 365 does not allow me to upload a *.json-file as a webresource, so I am not able to upload manifest.json.

So Firebase demand a manifest file, but dynamics does not allow it. 
I see other people already have done it so in one or other way it should be possible.

But is there a way around this?